# Fatal error! Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Tags: php, function, email, variables, fatal-error

i've made this simple shopping cart, where i've made this if and else function that goes inside a variable that gets called in my mail body, and this error message shows up when you submit the values:
Fatal error! Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Here's part of the variable function code:

```
$varer= function ($string) {
if ($_POST['smu']>= 1) 
{
"===========================================
Pilotjakke pelsforet Grå: \r\n
$pilotjakkegrå \r\n\r\n
===========================================" ;
}
else if($_POST['smu']<= 0)
{
    "";
}

//
```

and this is the email body part:

```
$body = "


Bekreftelse på bestilling:
\r\n\r\n 

Navn: $name_field\r\n 
===========================================
E-Mail: $email_field\r\n 
===========================================
Firma: $firma\r\n 
===========================================
Adresse: $adresse\r\n 
===========================================
Poststed: $poststed\r\n 
===========================================
Postnummer: $postnummer\r\n 
===========================================
Firma: $firma\r\n 
===========================================
Telefon: $tlf\r\n 
===========================================
Message: $message\r\n\r\n
=====================================================================================
Takk for at du bestilte hos oss, orderen din vil sett på og du vil motta en faktura snart. 
\r\n\r\n
=====================================================================================
Varebestillingen : 
$varer
\r\n\r\n
===========================================
Total Order Sum: $order kr
===========================================
";
```

and i get an error line where $varer is. I tried to convert it to a string but i probably did that all wrong.

You can take a look at the site here : http://www.premiere-produkter.no/pp/lagersalg/index.php

Comment: in which line does the error occur ?

Comment: varer= function ($string) { is missing a $ before varer

Comment: also better way of doing it would be $varer ($_POST['smu']>= 1) ?
"===========================================
Pilotjakke pelsforet Grå: \r\n
$pilotjakkegrå \r\n\r\n
==========================================="
:
  ""
;

Comment: ah it is $varer i just copied wrong, the error message is located after $varer , no matter what is there.

Comment: `$varer` is a function that requires a `$string` argument, which you're not passing.

Answer (score 0):

Your $varer is not a string but an object (instance of class Closure). You probably want to iterate over it's object properties.

Take a look at the examples on this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

If you really want to convert an object to a string you can use 'serialize()' (which doesn't work for closures), e.g.:

```
Varebestillingen : ".serialize($varer)."\r\n\r\n
```

To check the structure of your var use:

```
var_dump($varer);
```

Comment: I tried that but got this message

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed' in C:\zpiderwebs\DefaultWeb\1_F0001\pp\lagersalg\index.php:1028
Stack trace:
#0 C:\zpiderwebs\DefaultWeb\1_F0001\pp\lagersalg\index.php(1028): serialize(Object(Closure))
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\zpiderwebs\DefaultWeb\1_F0001\pp\lagersalg\index.php on line 1028

Comment: That's because we are dealing with a close here. You may want to var_dump($varer) to look at it's contents. More info here: http://www.bossduck.com/2009/07/php-5-3-closures-and-reflection/

Comment: I went for an easier way, i so overcomplicated everything i blinded myself. Because the variables in the $varer allready had an if / else function, i managed to fix those so that the only thing $varer does now is gather them together for the mail body :)